# What is a dialup access server?

Tags: route-server, dialup

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find what dialup access servers are, besides dialup access internet and other derivatives. Can you enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dialup *used to be* access via phone lines, using a modem or an ISDN terminal adapter. An access server had a bunch of modems (cascade) or TAs that could be dialed into by users.

The term is still in use by some for *remote access* using slightly more modern VPN solutions (IPsec or TLS) over the public Internet.